# Client-Server Model

Tags: html, client-server, p2p

I would like to develop a webpage (using any technology) with these conditions:

1. When client A types the web address on his browser, they automatically receive a remote IP (no other data)
2. With this IP, Client A automatically request some data from that IP (Client B)
3. Client B sends the requested information to Client A.

Which technology and libraries could I use to develop this webpage? (Javascript, Applets, browser plugin...) I think is some kind of P2P, so it should be possible to develop it.

Let's put one example.

- Imagine that the webpage I have to program is www.hi.com/test.html.
- I type it on my browser and receive automatically this IP: 212.22.62.106
- My browser automatically request data to 212.22.62.106, which is another client of www.hi.com/test.html
- This second client sends me the requested information, which is the only one is shown on my browser.

THANKS

Comment: I don't get it. Are you wanting for all of this to happen before the users actually visit your website?

Comment: The HTTP protocol has header information in the request/response transmissions. You can't browse a webpage with http and get less than the protocol allows. So, getting only an IP address doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about everything in browser security is going to fight this model - Ajax, javascript in general, applets, cookies - they're all tied to the current domain.

To do this, you're going to need to get something onto the desktop, if only in the form of an ActiveX control, which will severely limit your browser-base.

I think you're barking up the wrong tree - maybe if you could pop up one level of abstraction and tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this model?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with web page, you're looking in the wrong direction.

You'll have to build your own application which by the way sounds really similar to eMule.. :)